# getting undefined value in $http angular js

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS Code:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'saveEntity?formType=CompanyEntityModel',
  data: $.param($scope.obj), // pass in data as strings
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log("success");
  console.log(eval(data));
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log("Error Occured");
  console.log(eval(data));
});
```

Here is the backend code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveEntity" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveEntity(@RequestParam("formType") String 
formType,WebRequest request) throws Exception, 

 {
   String result1=MessageConstant.FAILURE_ADD_COMPANY;//variable 
   contains"failure"
try {
    pentaService.saveEntity(formType,request);
    result1=MessageConstant.SUCCESS_ADD_COMPANY;//variable contains 
  "success"
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

}
return result1;
```

}

In  success data I am sending "success" from server side but I am getting a undefined value  + its hitting the url, performing all task but its entering the error function ... I dont know why? how can I solved this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)- showing this error

Comment: There should not be eval just data should be there

Comment: Your api response is not right. You need to check that again.

Comment: Check in the browser console the response of API

Comment: new to AngularJs ..elaborate how to do....I have done console.log in browser showing undefined

Comment: it is going to success block or error block, also replace `.success` with `.then`

Comment: its going to error block ......but my server side logic is processing correct

Comment: why are you taking four parameters in response, what are you sending from api?, check `console.log(data);`

Comment: see in developer tool's network tab and check response. what you get from server?

Comment: console.log showing undefined  in place of  console.log(data);                                       

SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: so your response from sever is wrong? can you paste server code?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/saveEntity",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveEntity(@RequestParam("formType") String formType,WebRequest request) throws Exception
{
 
 
 String result1=MessageConstant.FAILURE_ADD_COMPANY;//contains failure
 try {
  pentaService.saveEntity(formType,request);
  result1=MessageConstant.SUCCESS_ADD_COMPANY;//contains success
 } catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  
 }
 
 return result1;
 
}

Comment: any help............

Comment: add that code in the question, what is that backend JAVA?

Comment: anybody have solution